# Modern turbos and oil pressure

Tags: turbocharger

One conventional "wisdom" for preventing turbocharger problems has always been to leave the motor running for half a minute or so before turning it off to give the turbo opportunity to spin out while oil pressure is still available.

Is this still useful advice for modern turbos (talking about the Kia/Hyundai 1.0 GDI engine)? If so, doesn't the start/stop automatic kind of nullify anything I do at the start and end of the drive?

Comment: When I considered a turbo some years age; They had automatic water and /or oil circulation for a few minutes after the engine was turned off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you come off the highway from doing 80mph and full boost, do an emergency stop and cut the engine then yes that can cause damage.

But if you have just trundled down the road to your drive and shunted then reversed to get in the garage it is likely the turbo is hardly spinning so it won’t matter.